# jQuery Mobile: Difference Between <a> and <button>

Tags: jquery, html, performance

Many of the examples on [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/grids-buttons/) use `<a href="#" ...>...</a>` for buttons instead of `<button>...</button>` for buttons that are NOT hyperlinks.  Is there is good reason for this? Will you find differences in behavior or performance on certain platforms when using one over the other?

Thank you.

Comment: The main reason that springs to mind is that a link tag `<a>` will work in browsers without JavaScript enabled, whereas a button (unless it's a submit button) won't do anything.

Comment: and you think jQuery Mobile is going to be that effective with Javascript disabled?

Comment: Using `<a href="#"` for "javascript buttons" is generally considered kind of a bad practice.

Comment: Yo Eric, I reckon there is a small misunderstanding so you can "Style links as buttons" but you can always use this `<button>Button element</button>`; so nowhere they are intending to comprehend that  `<a> === <button>` `:)` If you keen see here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! Although no "answers", I think I'm satisfied with the comments!

Comment: In tag **<a>** icons can be used, while in **<button>** can not